# Getting Not Desired size of file while backup mysql database using mysql dump

Tags: php

```
shell_exec('mysqldump --opt -Q -h ' . cDatabaseHost . ' -u ' . cDatabaseUser . ' --password=' . cDatabasePassword . ' ' . cDatabaseDatabase . ' | gzip > ' . $DatabaseFileName);
```

Above I have given my code, In which

When I want to get backup of my data. It creates random backup some time 50 MB and again I run it creates 10 MB, means every time different size. When the actual data backup size around about 500MB. Kindly Help me.
Thanks.